# SQL Transaction Stuck open

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hello I was creating a Stored PROC, so I went into a new Query typed out the following SQL to test before I create the Stored PROC and now when I type `select * From InvoicesT`; it just keeps trying without returning anything. I believe that the transaction is still open Please tell me away to close.

```
    BEGIN TRAN

        INSERT INTO InvoicesT(CompanyID,ContactsID, DueDate, Paid, Estimate, Billed) 
                    VALUES(
                           (SELECT c.[CompanyID] FROM CompanyT AS C WHERE c.ComapnyName = 'Jaila Files'),
                           (SELECT co.ID FROM ContactT as co WHERE co.LastName +', ' +co.FirstName = 'Tays, James'),
                           GETDATE()+7,
                           0,
                           0,
                           0
                           );
        go
        DECLARE @InvoiceNum int 
        @InvoiceNum = SELECT distinct SCOPE_IDENTITY() FROM InvoicesT

        Insert INTO InvoiceItems ([InvoiceNumber],[Amount],[Description],[EmployeeID],[Hours],[Product])
           VALUES (
                    @InvoiceNum, --Invoice Number
                    0.01, -- amount
                    'This is a Test', --Description
                    (SELECT e.EmpolyeeID FROM EmployeesT AS e WHERE e.FirstName = 'James' AND e.LastName = 'Tays'), -- EmployeeID
                    1, -- Hours
                    (SELECT p.ID FROM ProductsT as p WHERE p.ProductName = 'Excel')
                  )     
 COMMIT TRAN
```

There was an error on DECLARE @InvoiceNum

Comment: did you try to ROLLBACK?

Comment: no, how can I use ROLLBACK now that it is open?

Comment: Thank you, can you show me how to use ROLLBACK in transaction so this doesn't happen again?

Comment: wrap your code in a TRY---CATCH statement, and execute a ROLLBACK inside the CATCH.

Comment: if you want to be extra safe, you can check @@TRANCOUNT and if it is greater than 0, rollback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just execute

```
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

from the same query window.

The error didn't abort the transaction because you started the transaction in a separate batch before the GO.

If you don't have the same connection available you have to find and kill the transaction. See [close/kill transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833867/close-kill-transaction).